# isVowel() method with a character in a String

Tags: java, char

I have a text file with a bunch of words. One part of my program is supposed to, based on the user input, scan this list and insert into the output file the words that contain the requested number of vowels. I have a `isVowel` method that returns a `boolean`, but it doesn't seem to work--the output is just an empty list.

Here's the method:

```
public boolean isVowel(char c)
{
    if(c=='a' || c=='A' || c=='e' || c=='E' || c=='i' || c=='I' || c=='o' || c=='O' ||     c=='u' || c=='U')
    {    
        return true;
    }    
    else
    {
        return false;
    }    
}
}
```

Here's the part of the program where it is used:

```
public ArrayList<String> vowelHeavy(int n, int m)
{
    int vowels = 0;
    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {    
        word = input.nextLine();
        if (word.length() == n)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            {
                if(isVowel(word.charAt(i)) == true)
                {
                    vowels++;
                }
            }
            if (vowels == m)
            {
                output.add(word);
            }
        }
        word = input.nextLine();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Set `vowels` to 0 somewhere inside the `while` loop. Otherwise you count all vowels globally and not only per word.

Comment: what are your inputs?

Comment: By calling `word = input.nextLine();` twice, you're silently skipping over half your inputs.

Comment: Also, `isVowel()` should be `static` (it's just a "utility" function that doesn't rely on any class variables).

Comment: How about `áéíóöőúüű`? (and that was just one language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your biggest problem is you are not resetting you `vowels` counting variable when you test a new word. The value just keeps accumulating the total vowels *in the file*.

Change:

```
int vowels = 0;
while(input.hasNextLine()) {    
   ...
```

to:

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) {    
   int vowels = 0;
   ...
```

---

As an aside, most of your code, including the `isVowel()` method, could be eliminated with a single line:

```
int vowels = word.replaceAll("[^aeiouAEIOU]", "").length();
```

This works by eliminating from the word all characters that aren't vowels; what's left are the vowels, so just take the length to get the count.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a much easier way to write this code:

```
public boolean isVowel(char c){
   return(your boolean tests);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. If the `word.length() == n` test is never true, then `output` is never changed. Please make sure that test is correct.
2. This statement exists at the top AND bottom of the while loop, causing you to ignore every other input line:

   word = input.nextLine();